# How to ensure Cucumber doesn't print skipped steps?

Tags: cucumber

I have a long Cucumber scenario with only a few steps implemented, and many steps are pending. In my set up, Cucumber skips all pending steps, but still prints all the names of those skipped tests in the output, and that makes it tedious to scroll up to find the step where the scenario failed.

How can I make sure the skipped steps are not printed in the output? Ideally, I want the output to show all passing steps and the last failed step.

Comment: You would need to create a custom formatter - see the [cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no out of the box formatter that does exactly that. You would need to create a custom one but perhaps you could use the `progress` formatter. It prints information about the failed steps, green dots for the passing steps and dashes for the skipped ones:

```
>> cucumber --format progress

..............................F-

(::) failed steps (::)
"Error messages here"

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/dashboard.feature:13 # Scenario: Dashboard data is loaded

4 scenarios (1 failed, 3 passed)
26 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped, 24 passed)
0m41.604s
```

Also you can combine different formatters. One to give its output in the console and others to output its format in different files for later inspection. for example:

```
$ cucumber -f progress -f pretty --out results.txt -f rerun --out rerun.txt
```